# Showing in a simple way that the GCD of two polynomials is $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the GCD of $4x^5+7x^3+2x^2+1$ and $3x^3+x+1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

I understand, by looking at similar problems and talking to my friends, that it is $1$. However, I cannot find a way to show this without going through some nasty fractions, be it using the Euclidean Algorithm or just long division. Is it not $1$? If it is, is there a simpler, more elegant way to show it, other than nasty fractions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f(x), g(x)$ for your two polynomials. They're both primitive, so by [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) their irreducible factorization over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ consists of primitive irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Hence their gcd $h(x) = \gcd(f(x), g(x))$ has integer coefficients. By an examination of leading coefficients $h(x)$ must be monic, which implies that it can't have degree $3$ (since then it would be equal to $g(x)$ which can't divide $h(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$), so $\deg h(x) \le 2$.

This means $h(x)$ can take the value $1$ for integer values of $x$ at most twice without being identically equal to $1$ (since $h(x) - 1$ can have at most $2$ roots). So if we can find $3$ integer values $x_1, \dots x_4$ such that $\gcd(f(x_i), g(x_i)) = 1$ (these are $\gcd$s of ordinary integers now), this implies that $h(x) = 1$.

Now we calculate:

- $\gcd(f(0), g(0)) = \gcd(1, 1) = 1$
- $\gcd(f(-1), g(-1)) = \gcd(-8, -3) = 1$
- $\gcd(f(1), g(1)) = \gcd(14, 5) = 1$

So $h(x) = 1$.

---

A second approach is to prove that $g(x)$ is irreducible, which is not hard using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and then working $\bmod 2$; it follows that $h(x) = 1$ or $g(x)$, and we ruled out $h(x) = g(x)$ above.

Comment: I realize I'm assuming you want the $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$; there's slightly more work needed to justify these methods if you want the $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ or $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear: the question especifically asks to show it in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.Also, not sure if it will impact the resolution, but our professor was emphatic on us treating polynomials as formal sums and not as function. Thanks for all the help, I'll edit the original question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, we can justify working in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with Gauss's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)

Comment: @Rui: that's a strange thing to insist on. It sounds like your professor might want you to use the Euclidean algorithm specifically; that's a different question then.

Comment: @RuiAldéLopes Re previous comment, the *intent* of the questioner is important.  In this problem, for example, applying the polynomial-Euclidean_Algorithm is *kludgy*, but also tried and true, and doesn't require knowledge of the math in (for example) this answer.  When scrutinizing this answer, you might ask yourself whether the corresponding math theory has already been covered in your class.  **Meta-cheating**, why was this question posed at this time in your class?

Comment: @user2661923 The professor's intent has been hard to judge this semester, that's part of the problem, but I believe he is focusing on the structures of certain domains. We've seen in class, for instance, that if the ring A is a field then A[x] is an euclidean domain, if A is a factorial domain then so is A[x], Gauss's lemma (though a weird version of it), things like that. I would believe he wants us to use the algorithm, it just feels like there're better ways. Sorry for bringing this meta-cheating, I know it's not the point of this site.

Comment: @RuiAldéLopes Although I'm the only one that uses the explicit term meta-cheating, the underlying concept is implicit in at least part of the reason why mathSE reviewers ask the OP for **background.**  Personally, I consider **meta-cheating** (re taking a step back and [among other things] considering the human factor) to be legitimately applicable at the undergraduate level and below.  Meta-cheating also involves (for example) assuming that an assigned problem is solvable, and usually by the means discussed in class.